# Win 2012 AD security group permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012

After i created a security group in AD and added members to it i shared a folder and gave permission to that group, but none of the users can access the folder. Any help suggestions will help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Check that the group has permission for both the *share* and the *folder* (NTFS permissions).
2. A user must logout and login before these changes will take effect.